No signature of method: io.restassured.internal.ContentParser.parse()
I'm upgrading my application tomcat to 10. As part of that I'm upgrading required dependencies. I have upgraded my rest-assured dependency version from 3.3.0 to 5.3.0. After that, I'm getting following error while executing tests.
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: io.restassured.internal.ContentParser.parse() is applicable for argument types: (io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl, io.restassured.internal.ResponseParserRegistrar...) values: [io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@307af381, io.restassured.internal.ResponseParserRegistrar@1510b9a2, ...]
Possible solutions: wait(), grep(), any()
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:70)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:50)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:497)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:696)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.this$2$validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:189)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:57)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.body(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:270)
at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$body$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$body$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.body(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:117)
at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.body(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:244)
at com.test.mytest(MyApiTest.java:120)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:54)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:54)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)

I'm trying basic rest-assured assertion check like below
given()
    .when()
        .get("/myapi")
    .then()
        .statusCode(200)
        .body("size()", is(3)) //getting error in this line

I have below dependency added already
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


The above issue is fixed after updating dependencies like below.
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.22</version>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>

References:
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/923
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted#java-9
